# RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue is showing error

Tags: c#, .net, azure, connection-string, azure-worker-roles

I have added azure project in my application and added database connection string values in the settings tag named "MasterDBConnection" under .cscfg file like below:

```
<Role name="projWorkerRole">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Enabled" value="true" />
      <Setting name="MasterDBConnection" value="Server=u3oUIUIIY1v.database.windows.net;Database=ABCDTest;User ID=11;Password=rCVyqbcmSraLq8bjBXNcYyfPyvNqRu;Trusted_Connection=False;connection timeout=120;Max Pool Size = 500;Pooling = True;" />
      <Setting name="StateDBConnection" value="Server=u3oUIUIIY1v.database.windows.net;Database=ASPState;User ID=relate;Password=rCVyqbcmSraLq8bjBXNcYyfPyvNqRu;Trusted_Connection=False;connection timeout=120;Max Pool Size = 500;Pooling = True;" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountUsername" value="abcd" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword" value="MMMMIIBSgIBADAyMB4xHDAaBgNVBAMME1dpbmRvd3MgQXp1cmUgVG9vbHMCEBoNpt+iYi+ZQhZlsYE7ZyIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggEAT5HQNweks5KCwtn5inNGrh7w4txgYA75ow/EB5DAmw4AozyKN6FoapXaGyizTU/U7Om+oUbad36IddxNZBp9dDCtS62HlDME8bCCc0tjrvViN0AX8p0l6wlTS0bh8bkZ6R18TbDrR8wnt/BZEkT0a8ynTeY9vYP8GwSNcqIoNSe6dThKeT/vmjqZYjDQrUcUhP7MwwIkhWyMk5svId2mkigHpkwUfCE2QsZh5Yau+eAIhbhy5LKgt/fPZec3fs21JPjZT2yOSQ4Nnagij1ITfG97EQqjl35mq0Es6Jy/BZXNgfF9XWD6zFnAL3t7vQ9Yb2gFRhsLiFh0pFq+E9a8ATAzBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwFAYIKoZIhvcNAwcECHZXItflnlNUg..." />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountExpiration" value="2026-16-27T23:59:59.0000000+05:30" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption" thumbprint="04A23427944E036103F686C4DD...." thumbprintAlgorithm="dha1" />
    </Certificates>
  </Role>
```

Now when I'm calling the connection string value from .cscfg file it's showing an error.
I'm calling the connection string like below:

```
string connMaster = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("MasterDBConnection");
```

The error is showing like below:

```
    An exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironmentException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: error
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on my side. It works correctly for me. You could refer to this [tutorial](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/vs-azure-tools-configure-roles-for-cloud-service.md#add-custom-settings-to-use-in-your-azure-cloud-service) to get more information about how to add custom settings to use in your Azure cloud service.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. The connection string was not added under web settings.